# Не проходит нужное количество итераций в цикле for

Tags: python

```py
d1 = {i:'-' for i in range(1,12)}
d2 = {}
n = input().split()
for j in n:
    d2[n[0]] = [int(n[2])]
    if d2 in d2[n[0]]:
        d2[n[0]] += [int(n[2])]
    n = input().split()
print(d2)
```

Надо ввести условно:

```
4   Quincy  135
6   Bootman 151
2   Audley  126
6   Sheldon 156
5   Bootman 147
4   Quincy  141
7   Pass    161
6   Foster  159
6   Larkins 151
5   Dowman  145
11  Kennett 174
7   Brooks  161
4   Warren  138
4   Hodges  136
```

Но цикл почему то проходит только 3 строки, и завершает выполнение.
Как сделать чтобы цикл обрабатывал столько строк, сколько я введу?

Comment: `if d2 in d2[n[0]]:` - что-то я подозреваю, что это условие никогда не выполнится

Comment: @andreymal, оно, может, и так, но первая проблема в том, что ввод строк неверно выполнен:-) Там обрабатывается только первая строка, потому и выполняется цикл всего три раза.

Comment: Ошибку я выше написал. Так как нет ни комментариев в коде, ни описания, что код делает, то как исправить - подумайте сами. Например, можно как-то сообщить n, что больше не будет ничего вводиться?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ответ на вопрос**: почему всего 3 итерации?

Потому что длина n = 3, и вы запускаете `for` для этих 3 членов списка.

Как исправить:

**Вариант 1**

использовать `while` до тех пор пока не будет пустой строки или проще, пока не нажмете <kbd>Enter</kbd> при стандартном вводе. Пример:

```py
while True:
  n = input()
  if n:
    # do something
    s = n.split()
    print(s)
  else:
    break
```

**Вариант 2 (менее предпочтителен)**

Определить количество строк в начале и использовать конструкцию `for`. Менее гибкий вариант, поскольку изначально надо знать сколько раз вы будете вводить данные. Пример:

```py
how_many_rows = int(input("Введите количество строк (целое число)\n"))
for i in range(how_many_rows):
    n = input().split()
    # do something
    print(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pprint import pprint
data = dict()

while line := input('Введите данне: '):
    index, *_, code = line.split()
    data[index] = data.get(index, []) + [int(code)]

pprint(data)
#{'11': [174],
# '2': [126],
# '4': [135, 141, 138, 136],
# '5': [147, 145],
# '6': [151, 156, 159, 151],
# '7': [161, 161]}
```